# escaping the leading 'b' in python

Tags: python, byte, output

I was trying to strip a string like

```
var/vob/bxxxxx/xxxxx/vob
```

I am doing it like...

```
'var/vob/bxxxxx/xxxxx/vob'.lstrip('/var/vob/')
```

I am expecting an output like ...

```
bxxxxx/xxxx/vob
```

But it is only giving...

```
xxxx/xxxxxx/vob
```

Yes I know because of the first letter is b and in python prefix b for a string stands for converting it into bytes, and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) too...

But what I wanted to know is how to bypass this thing.. I want to get the desired output...

I would love to say the things I have tried.. but I don't find any way around to try... can some one throw some light on this...

Thanks :)

Comment: Your sample string doesn't even begin with your `lstrip` argument, since it lacks the leading `/`. If you want to chop a fixed prefix off a string, I'd test `startswith(prefix)` and then slice, something like `test[len(prefix):]`.

Comment: Oh, and in response to this part: "in python prefix b for a string stands for converting it into bytes" - that refers to a) only Python 3.x and b) refers to using `b` as a marker outside the quotes. In Python 3, this would be a literal for a `bytes` object: `b'foo'`, while this would be a literal for a string object: `'bfoo'`. In Python 2.x, the `u` marker serves an inverse purpose - `'foo'` is an encoded string, while `u'foo'` is a Unicode object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
if s.startswith("var/vob/):
    s = s[8:]
```

And yes, Mark is right, `lstrip` removes any haracters from contained in the argument from the string.

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand what `lstrip` does. It removes *all* characters that are part of the parameter string. Order doesn't matter. Since `b` is in the string it is removed from the front of the result.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, that comment would be better left on the original question.

Comment: Fair enough - I thought of it as expanding your answer (which explains why the OP's attempt didn't work) by suggesting an alternate approach, but no matter.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be, like this

```
data, text = "/var/vob/bxxxxx/IT_test/vob", "/var/vob/"
if data.startswith(text): data = data[len(text):]
print data
```

**Output**

```
bxxxxxx/IT_test/vob
```